# Changes to existing sqlite revert back to original

Tags: database, sqlite, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6

I,m working on an mobile flex application using flash Builder 4.6 and Flex 4.6, I have a SQlite db file in bin-debug folder that I copy to applicationStorageDirectory in ActionScript when the application starts.

Here is the script that setups the database it called on app initialize event:

```
        /* Variables*/

        private var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("db/myHealthBuddy.db");
        private var local:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("db/myHealthBuddy.db");
        private var conn:SQLConnection;
        private var model:Model = new Model();

        /* db */
        protected function dbInit():void
        {           

            if(!local.exists)
            {
                local.createDirectory();
                file.copyTo(local,true);
            }
            conn = new SQLConnection();
            conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler);
            conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
            conn.openAsync(local);
        }

        private function openHandler(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            trace("\ndb open");
            conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler);

            // saving connection to Model valueObject 
            model.connection = conn;

            // create tables if not already exists
            var createTablesFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("db" + File.separator + "createtables.xml");
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            stream.open(createTablesFile, FileMode.READ);
            var xml:XML = XML(stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable));
            stream.close();
            conn.begin(SQLTransactionLockType.IMMEDIATE);
            for each (var statement:XML in xml.statement)
            {
                var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
                stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                stmt.text = statement;
                stmt.execute();         
            }
            conn.commit();


            navigator.firstViewData = model;
        }
```

Is this code ok.

I need to make changes to the database e.g.(add new tables and add columns to existing tables). When I make these changes to the sqlite db they revert back but presist in the xml file which contains the tables creations SQL.

Comment: Do you copy the database from bin-debug to application storage directory each time the app starts; therefore, reverting the database each runtime?

Comment: Yes I do, but the changes I make to the sqlite db file in bin-debug folder reverts back. the db in applicationStorageDirectory should be copied over by the changed sqlite db file.